# Why my dialog box isn't working out?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm making a dialog box by my own coding as i run this code nothing happens and neither my `signup!!` link is working, My Approach is just like when i click to `signup!!` link, a modal box should appear, but nothing happens such this, My Jquery library is in correct path so it has to deal nothing with this..

Here is my pic when i run my code it directly shows modal box without clicking `signup!!` link: [click here](http://postimg.org/image/udantwzep/)

Why is my dialog box not working?

Here is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a.dialog-window').click(function(){

                    var signUpBox=$(this).attr('href');

                    $(signUpBox).fadeIn(400);

                     $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
                     $('#mask').fadeIn(300);    
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function(){
                        $('#mask, .dialog_box').fadeOut(400, function(){
                            $('#mask').remove();
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
        </script>
        <style>
            .dialog_box{
                width: 70%;
                height: 70%;
                background-color: #520832;
                position: fixed;
                left: 15%;
                top: 15%;            
                -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0px 38px #520832;
                -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 38px #520832;
                box-shadow: -1px 0px 38px #520832;
            }

            .close{
                position: fixed;
                right: 14%;
                top: 10%; 
            }            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#dialog" class="dialog-window">Signup!!</a>

        <div id="dialog" class="dialog_box">
            <a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>

            <h2 style="color: #E2E2E2; font-family: Aileron, sans-serif; text-align: center;">Signup Now!</h2>

            <form method="post" class="signUp" action="#">

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not telling the browser that your dialog box shouldn't be visible before the link is clicked. Add `display: none;` to the dialog box's CSS rule. Like this:

```css
.dialog_box
{
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: #520832;
    position: fixed;
    left: 15%;
    top: 15%;            
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0px 38px #520832;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 38px #520832;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 38px #520832;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: ya you were right but one more problem when i click to close button, it doesn't disappear.. can you tell me what's wrong here? :(

Comment: I think your problem is that you're selecting multiple elements when you select a.close and #mask. Try assigning a class to both of them and adding an event to that class instead.

Comment: can you tell me how to do tis i'm a begineer

Comment: Actually, I was wrong: the issue is that you're adding the `click` event to the `#mask` element before it's created. Move the `$('a.close, #mask').live(...)` part up before the `return false;` statement.